# Proguard - Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

Tags: java, android

I have issues with proguard, I just configured Bugsense and I have used they configuration advices, I have searched on google and stackoverflow and usually ppl can see in console the line or problem, but in my case I can't know wich is the conflict.

I'm newbie in android.

This is my log->

```
[2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer] proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member description or closing '}' before '-include' in argument number 5
    [2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1133)
    [2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:685)
    [2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
    [2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:138)
    [2013-10-24 21:20:56 - UploadToServer]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

This is my proguard-project.txt

```
-optimizationpasses 25 
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames 
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses 
-dontpreverify 
-verbose 
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/* 
-printmapping out.map 
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile 
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable 
-keep class com.bugsense.** { *; } 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service 
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver 
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider 
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper 
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference 
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService 

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { 
    native <methods>; 
} 

-keepclasseswithmembers class * { 
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
} 

-keepclasseswithmembers class * { 
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
} 

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
   public void *(android.view.View); 
} 

-keepclassmembers enum * { 
    public static **[] values(); 
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); 
} 

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable { 
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
```

And this is my project.properties

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
-keep class com.bugsense.** { *; }
-libraryjars libs/bugsense-3.5.jar
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `}` at the end your proguard config.

Comment: OMG yes, Varun thanks, thats a stupid error I was trying to fix almost 2 hours.. Thanks :-)

Comment: Well, your log says that there is a `}` missing. Seeing your `proguard` config it certainly looks like a `}` missing at the end.

Comment: Do you known if proguard is really secure for decompillers? or is another way to encypt or smth, Greetens

Comment: Proguard only obfuscates and simplifies code. A decompiler can still decompile, but the decompiled code will be really less readable. AFAIK, there is no real protection. YOu can also take a look at DexGuard - http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard